# React Button - Changes Text onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to teach myself React and I have a 'Bop it' button function that changes the text on each click.

```
      function BopButton() {

        const [action, setAction] = React.useState('');
        const actions = ['Bop', 'Twist', 'Spin', 'Pull'];

        function handleClick() {
          const len = actions.length;
          setAction(actions[Math.floor(Math.random() * len)].text)
          console.log("change text")
        }

        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>{action} it</button>
          </div>
        );
      }
```

I'm expecting the state of the button text to change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `.text` from `setAction(actions[Math.floor(Math.random() * len)].text)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`actions` is an *array* of *strings*, not *array* of objects. You don't have to access the text with `.text` property, because it just **does not** exist.

Just remove it.

```
setAction(actions[Math.floor(Math.random() * len)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you just had a redundant `.text`
I refactored a bit to make it more readable:

```
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react'

const actions = ['Bop', 'Twist', 'Spin', 'Pull']
const BopButton = () => {
  const [action, setAction] = useState(actions[0])

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    setAction(actions[Math.floor(Math.random() * actions.length)])
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>{action} it</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default BopButton
```